# i get cannot find symbol error in compile time

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 class pbdemo {

     static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         String s;
         try {
             ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/f", "dir");
             pb.directory(new File("F:\\WINDOWS"));
             pb.start();
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.getInputStream()));

             while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
             System.out.println(s);

         } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("sorry" + e);
         }
     }
 }
```

what is the problem in

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.getInputStream()));
```

I get cannot find symbol error.

Comment: How about cut and paste the actual error message. It should tell you which of the 3 possibilities on that one line can't be found.

Comment: seem duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286042/im-not-getting-any-output-and-probably-the-machine-hangs-with-the-code

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an `InputStream` from a `ProcessBuilder` and that's wrong.

`ProcessBuilder.start()` returns a Process object, and that's the one who has a `getInputStream()` method.

Try switching that line for this one.

`BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.start().getInputStream()));`

Or

```
Process pro = pb.start();
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer.

`ProcessBuilder` don't have `getInputStream` method.

See this: [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

You can use:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.start().getInputStream()));
```