# Process is being paused until I close the program

Tags: java, swing, ffmpeg

I made a simple program and UI for it.
It has one button for starting ffmpeg.exe to decode a video:

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("D:\\ffmpeg.exe", "-i", "\"D:\\video\\input.mp4\"", "\"output.mp4\"");
            try {
                Process p = pb.start();
            } catch (IOException error) {
                //
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that after clicking the button ffmpeg starts but it doesn't do anything (in task manager it doesn't use cpu - 0%) until I close the program (UI) and then ffmpeg process starts to decode a video (only after closing the program ffmpeg starts using cpu - e.g. 24%)

**It's not duplicate**: older questions proposed by **Andy Thomas** doesn't have an answer (solution) for my problem

Comment: Does running your command in cmd works?
```D:\\ffmpeg.exe -i D:\\video\\input.mp4\ \output.mp4\```

Comment: it seems as a output path error to me already

Comment: @FahadSiddiqui there is no such error, sorry. As I already said it works but only when I close the program

Comment: You have to read the output from the process, or it will block until you do. There´s probably already a question on this. Looking ...

Comment: @AndyThomas nothing of those helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15349973/7767664 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/15286128/7767664 ffmpeg still on 0% cpu.. until I close the program

Comment: Are you consuming both stdout and stderr from the started process? Do you have a worker thread dedicated to each of these to prevent the UI from blocking?

Comment: @AndyThomas my UI isn't being blocked

Comment: So presumably you must be using worker threads, then, to read from both stdout/stderr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Process` blocks the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Instead, run your [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) in the background of a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html), as shown in this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20603012/230513).

```
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                "D:\\ffmpeg.exe", "-i", "\"D:\\video\\input.mp4\"", "\"output.mp4\""));
        …
    }
```

Note that the example invokes `redirectErrorStream(true)`, so you should be able to see any errors or prompts from `ffmpeg.exe`.