# capturing error message and to display in console (IDE)

Tags: java, outputstream, system.out, bytearrayoutputstream, printstream

I am running a c++ program (makefile) as a background process using Processbuilder from my java Program. I am capturing the values displayed in my cmd prompt using .getInputStream and displaying in my console (IDE) .

```
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line;
    try {
       while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(line);
```

This works well. Suppose if i make some error in one of my c++ file and when i try to run the makefile it is not capturing the error message. On using "cmd.exe","start" i can view the error in cmd prompt but it is not displayed in the console(IDE) .

May i know what i should do to get the error message displayed.

1) System.err and printstream could be the solution for this ? if it so could you be please show me a sample piece of code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you use [ProcessBuilder#redirectError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectError(java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect))?

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer.

Comment: if it is an error i can get it through redirectError as menthioned by you. I can get the output through .getInputStream. If i run an exe at background its processing is not captured either by errorstream or inputstream. How can i get that?

Comment: If you use redirectError, the error output will be redirected to the InputStream. Instead of using BufferedReader#readLine, try reading each character individually

Comment: Try taking a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286042/im-not-getting-any-output-and-probably-the-machine-hangs-with-the-code/15286128#15286128)

Answer (score 2):

Process has `.getErrorStream()` or you can use ProcessBuilder's `.redirectErrorStream()` as mentioned by MadProgrammer's comment and this SO Question:
[Java Process with Input/Output Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream)

Comment: @sreram if you like someone's answer, or it solved your problem, then you should upvote it and/or mark it best answer. Comments do not apply, but you can still give them an up.